# Firefox Title And Menu bar resets

Tags: firefox, mate, merge

So, i basically want my Firefox title and Menu bar merged.
like the  ( _ □ X ) symbols

I searched around and found an answer:
`go to Firefox Menu --> Customize... --> Untick the title bar Square.`
but whenever i restart my firefox, the Title bar reappears!
the box isn't ticked, but the title bar is there!

I'm running version `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, Codename focal`

`Im using the firefox December 15, 2020 Update. 84.0 Mozila Firefox for ubuntu`

```
Related: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/title-bar-re-appears-when-resizing-firefox-window-with-title-bar-off/17395/4
```

edit2: i think the problem is fixed after restarting firefox....
but im not so sure so ill mark is solved for now, i guess?

edit3: oh no it's back here's a screenshot
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekrso.png)

Comment: You've tagged both Unity and GNOME. Which one are you using?

Comment: Can you edit to post a screenshot? (right now you can only post an image as a link, but we will fix that)